# How to use Inception-v3 as a convolutional network

Tags: python, computer-vision, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

So, I've retrained the Inception-v3 network to classify specific kinds of data - for training I've provided it with 200x200 pictures. Now, when I run the graph on another 200x200 picture it works just fine. What I want to achieve is to turn it into a filter for a convolutional network - i.e. slide it as a filter through the whole picture and get the probability of each pixel being in a given class.

It seems to be fairly simple to do manually - just splice the picture into small sections, classify each of them, put the results together and voila. But that would be very inefficient. Instead, I want to do something like what is described here: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convert. Basically, change the last FC layer and turn it into a CONV layer by reshaping the weights. Seems simple enough, but I can't figure out how to actually do this.

My main problem is that at the end of the Inception-v3 net, right before the last FC layer, there's a pooling operation that reformats the data into (1,2048) shape, so I won't really be able to perform a convolution here.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: What you mean is a fully convolutional network, and you should use that terminology to make it less confusing.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I am also interested in this. Any news?

Answer (score 0):

My most immediate solution for this is to skip the fully connected layer in the end as it would cause the input image to lose its initial structure. Doing a `Conv -> FC -> Conv` seems redundant